# java client send class and server execute a method from this files

Tags: java, client-server, distributed-computing

Im working on a little project.

My client send a java file :

```
public class Calc { 
    public int add(String a, String b){
        int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

My server receive this file in his package. There is no problem for this.
What i want its to excecute 'public int add' in my server with parameter send by client.
For example: my client connects to server.
He send Calc.java and with a String add("1","2")
My server receive this and execute the function to finnaly return the result.

But i dont know how to do this... i just find "execute" but ihavent a main method in Calc.java

Is this possible to do that ? With what method ?

Comment: RMI should be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really, *really,* ***really*** bad idea. You don't want to send source code around and then execute it as part of a running application. There are horrific security risks.

Have a look at RMI, as suggested by @JunedAhsan: it already does exactly what you are trying to do, but in a secure way, and without the source code aspect.